# Why Kubernetes Services are created before Deployment/Pods?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-deployment

If I have to deploy a workload on Kubernetes and also have to expose it as a service, I have to create a Deployment/Pod and a Service. If the Kubernetes offering is from Cloud and we are creating a LoadBalancer service, it makes sense to create the the service first before the workload as the url creation for the service takes time. But in case the Kubernetes deployed on non-cloud platform there is no point in creating the Service before the workload.
So why I have to create a service first then the workload?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: The question is, If I have to create a Pod/Deployment and a service for it, why the service is created first?

Comment: It doesn't matter in what order you create Service and Deployment. AFAIK, it is just a convention to create the service before its pods. One reason to create a service before its pods could be to start serving traffic as soon as the first pod is ready. This is especially true in the case of Stateful sets of HTTP workloads, where pods will be created one by one, but you can start serving requests as soon as the first one is ready.

Comment: As i wrote in my answer there is at least a case where you need to create a service BEFORE the pods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no requirement to create a service before a deployment or vice versa. You can create the deployment before the service or the service before the deployment.

If you create the deployment before the service, then the application packaged in the deployment will not be accessible externally until you create the LoadBalancer.

Conversely, if you create the LoadBalancer first, the traffic for the application will not be routed to the application as it hasn't been created yet, giving 503s to the caller.

You are declaring to Kubernetes how you want the state of the infrastructure to be. e.g. "I want a deployment and a service". Kubernetes will go off and create those, but they may not necessarily end up being creating in a predictable order. For example, LoadBalancers take a while to assign IPs from your Cloud provider, so even though the resource is created in the cluster, it's not actually getting any traffic.

Answer (score 2):

As wrote in the official kubernetes documentation, and unlike to what other users have told you, there is a specific case that the service needs to be created BEFORE the pod.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#environment-variables

> Note:
> When you have a Pod that needs to access a Service, and you are using the environment variable method to publish the port and cluster IP to the client Pods, you must create the Service before the client Pods come into existence. Otherwise, those client Pods won't have their environment variables populated.
> If you only use DNS to discover the cluster IP for a Service, you don't need to worry about this ordering issue.

For example:

Create some pods, deploy and service in a namespace:

##### namespace.yaml

```yaml
# namespace

apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: securedapp
spec: {}
status: {}
```

##### services.yaml

```yaml
# expose api svc

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    type: api
  name: api-svc
  namespace: securedapp
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 90
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    type: api
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}


---
# expose frontend-svc

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    type: secured
  name: frontend-svc
  namespace: securedapp
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    type: secured
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

##### pods-and-deploy.yaml

```yaml
# create the pod for frontend
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    type: secured
  name: secured-frontend
  namespace: securedapp
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: secured-frontend
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
---

# create the pod for the api

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    type: api
  name: webapi
  namespace: securedapp
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: webapi
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}

---
# create a deploy

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: sure-even-with-deploy
  name: sure-even-with-deploy
  namespace: securedapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sure-even-with-deploy
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: sure-even-with-deploy
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

If you create all the resources contextually in the same time, for example placing all this files on a folder, then do an apply on it like this:
`kubectl apply -f .`

Then if we get the envs from one pod
`k exec -it webapi -n securedapp  -- env`

you will obtain something like this:

```bash
# environment of api_svc
API_SVC_PORT_90_TCP=tcp://10.152.183.242:90
API_SVC_SERVICE_PORT=90
API_SVC_PORT_90_TCP_ADDR=10.152.183.242
API_SVC_SERVICE_HOST=10.152.183.242
API_SVC_PORT_90_TCP_PORT=90
API_SVC_PORT=tcp://10.152.183.242:90
API_SVC_PORT_90_TCP_PROTO=tcp

# environment of frontend
FRONTEND_SVC_SERVICE_HOST=10.152.183.87
FRONTEND_SVC_SERVICE_PORT=80
FRONTEND_SVC_PORT=tcp://10.152.183.87:280
FRONTEND_SVC_PORT_280_TCP_PORT=80
FRONTEND_SVC_PORT_280_TCP=tcp://10.152.183.87:280
FRONTEND_SVC_PORT_280_TCP_PROTO=tcp
FRONTEND_SVC_PORT_280_TCP_ADDR=10.152.183.87
```

Clear all the resoruces created:
`kubectl delete -f .`

### Now, another try.

This time we will do the same thing but "slowly", we create things one by one.

Sure, the ns first
`k apply -f ns.yaml`

then the pods
`k apply -f pods.yaml`

After a while create the services

`k apply -f services.yaml`

Now you will discover that if you get the envs from one pod
`k exec -it webapi -n securedapp  -- env`
this time you will NOT have the environment variables of the services.

So, as mentioned on the k8s documentation there is at least one case, where it is necessary to create the svc BEFORE the pods: if you need env variables of your services.

Saluti